# Is there a way to find out which modules are imported the most in a Webpack bundled app?

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to sort all imported modules in a Webpack bundled app by most frequently imported?

**Background for question:**

I have just taken over development for an application that has very little test coverage. I would like to increase the test coverage, but I have to decide which functions / modules I need to tackle first. So I'm looking for a way to decide which modules are actually most important for the app.

Answer (score 0):

i believe your looking for [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer), here is a example of what it does:
[image]

Comment: I've considered Webpack Bundle Analyzer, but AFAIK it mainly displays the size of each module in relation to the bundle. It does not measure importance to the app. Which is why I'm looking for a heuristic to determine the importance of all the (self authored) modules in a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

While i am not pointing out any solution to your actual question, would like to point out that one should concentrate more on

1. the functionalities/modules **actually used by majority of the application users**.
2. the current test coverage

Based on those, one should pick the modules that users are **using the most** with **less** test coverage.

(1) above is something that can only be known by talking to customers directly or the product/application management.

For (2), There are couple of javascript code coverage tools available in the market.

Please do note that most imported/used modules may not be the power modules i.e. used by most users.

Comment: Since the application has not been released yet there are no customers to talk to to determine the usage of specific functions of the application. Which is why I have to turn to a different heuristic at this stage to determine which self authored module I have to focus on first in terms of test coverage.

From reading the code base, I know that some modules are big and are used a lot. But this is more of a hunch right now than based on facts. 

Which is why I'm looking for a way to determine which modules are used most. I'm guessing Webpack can do this as it builds a dependency graph.